# Do I need to do application licencing for a new app in android market?

Tags: android, android-lvl

I have uploaded my first app to android market a while ago - no there is a comment that the copy protection will expire and I should use licencing instead.

**Does that mean I need to do this licencing for my new paid app as well or can I just export it with the Keystore and do the licencing later? But the app is still copy protected, even without licencing?**

By the way, how much effort is it to integrate this licencing stuff into my app? Reading through the docs it seems quite an effort!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you will finally go with new LVL after all, it is better to start using it sooner than later. There is a sample app (contains only one single activity) along with the LVL lib maven which is pretty handy. From my own experience, since I use maven, I direct copy LVL src into my application, to implement the licensing verification, most time I just borrow/copy code from the sample application. Once you read [their official dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) and get a general idea, you should able to migrate the LVL into your application within 15 minutes.